# Moving front page (cursebird or foursquare)

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, jquery

Ok so I'll be honest, I have a good amount of experience with php/mysql, I've just started learning jQuery and I've done very little, but some with ajax. So using the terms ajax/jquery interchangeably are a bit confusing to me. Anyway as the title suggest I have a website with 5 items, and I want them to move (meaning, if a more recent one is entered, remove the last item, and put the new one on top), they are 5 of the most recent items in the database table, now I've coded jquery as a test so it fades out the last one, the whole thing moves down, makes room at the top, and fades in a new one. However, it's a test and has 0 interaction with the database, the one that fades in is just in a hidden div. So the jQuery part is taken care of.

So I'm unsure how to go about this, I was thinking maybe have ajax check a website off the page that has those 5 items in raw format, and if they change then to refresh?

Not looking for a "plz code 4 me" answer, just the concept of how it would work, or some links to get off to the right start.

edit - Also, the 5 items are ranked, so if I click item 3 I need it to move above item 2 refreshlessly, so this causes a whole other issue I assume.

Answer (score 0):

Your AJAX solution sounds reasonable, but...

How frequently will the database be updated? If you are getting updates every few minutes then this will work fine if you are getting 100 updates a second then users may get strange results.

How frequently do you plan on polling the server and with how many users?

Just a couple of thoughts.

Comment: Well the ideal would be as many users as facebook? :P. No but I want it to be capable for a large community, also I have changed the issue slightly. - gonna note it in original post.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is that jQuery (the javascript toolkit) makes an Ajax request (this could be done with raw javascript, but jQuery makes the process SO much easier) to a script (PHP, in your case), which will query the database and then return the data.

Your basic script (for the call and response) would probably be something along these lines:

**ajax-handler.php**

```
<?php
    if( isset($_POST['get-store-updates']) ){
        $output = '';
        $sql = "SELECT ... LIMIT 5"; // Select the five store items
        $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

        while( $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) ){
            $output .= // construct the HTML for your store items
        }

        echo $output;
    }
?>
```

**index.php**

```
function get_items(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'ajax-handler.php',
        type: 'post',
        data: 'get-store-updates=true',
        success: function(myItems){
            $('#item-wrapper').html(myItems);
        }
    });
}
```

In this example, *something* triggers the get_items() javascript function, which fires off the ajax call (a POST request to ajax-handler.php with parameters "get-store-updates=true", which satisfy the "if( isset($_POST['get-store-updates']) )" I put in the PHP). If the Ajax request is successful (meaning it executed the call, not necessarily that the PHP script worked), the output of the PHP script becomes the javascript variable "myItems." With our PHP response stored in a javascript variable, we can easily replace the contents of the item list (in this case, #item-wrapper) using any number of jQuery methods.

Of course, if you're engineering this for a large community, you'll want to make preparations for a high server load. If you really want to get fancy, look into data push methods.